# Event handler not accessing the correct value from redux state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, addeventlistener

In my web application, I want to prompt user when he/she tries to close the browser/tab based upon Redux state using event handlers.

I am using the below code to prompt user before exiting based upon 'isLeaving' state.

```
function mapStateToProps(state) {
    const {isLeaving} = state.app.getIn(['abc']);
    return {
        isLeaving
    };
}

@connect(mapStateToProps, {}, undefined, {withRef: true})
export default class MyClass extends React.component {
    @autobind
    stayOnPage(event) {
        if (this.props.isLeaving) {
            const message = 'Are you sure you want to leave';
            event.returnValue = message;
            return message;
        }
        return false;
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
            this.stayOnPage(event);
        });
    }

    componentWillUnmount() {
        window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
            this.stayOnPage(event);
        });
    }



    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
        if (this.props.prop1 !== nextProps.prop2) {
           // do something
        }
    }

    render() {
       //
    }
}
```

This code works fine. But whenever there is a change in prop1, I see that this.props.isLeaving does not have updated value.

Can somebody help? What is I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: The `isLeaving` prop is passed in from redux state, but there is nothing in this component to update that state in redux, so `isLeaving` remains its initial passed in value.

Comment: isLeaving prop is being updated from some other piece of code. So when state gets updated in redux, shouldn't this component also be rerendered and have latest value. The problem is i want to check only the latest value. Is there a way out?

Answer (score 1):

You aren't cleaning up correctly in componentWillUnmount. The event handler you're trying to remove is a brand new function closure, not the same instance that you added. You should just attach the actual handler, rather than using an arrow function, like so:

```
componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.stayOnPage);
}

componentWillUnmount() {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.stayOnPage);
}
```

Possibly what you are seeing is the event triggering on a stale component instance, so it has old state.

Comment: Thanks Peter. This solved my use case and upon debugging I found that event was triggering on stale component instance

Answer (score 0):

React uses synthetic events, basically events are recycled to be more performant. You can read more on that [here](https://appendto.com/2017/01/react-events-101/)

What I normally do is pass the value I need on invocation

Not sure if this will work in your specific case because I define my event handlers in JSX instead of accessing the `window` object (which you might want to do as well but to be honest I'm not sure) but I use this pattern all the time to handle `e.target.value` properly

Comment: I want always the latest value of isLeaving ti be checked. thanks for synthetic events link. can you explain a bit more?

Comment: basically React has one single SyntheticEvent object. Everytime a SyntheticEvent is called (not all events are targeted by this)  the SyntheticEvent object is populated with data about that event. Point being, you can't count on the SyntheticEvent object to contain the data you expect it to contain